# (AMS)TeX proclaim environment

Tags: theorems, amstex

AMSTeX has a `\proclaim` macro that goes like this:

```
\proclaim{Theorem 10} 
Text of the theorem
\endproclaim
```

which results in

**Theorem 10.** *Text of the theorem*.

In other words, this environment adds a dot (.) after the number. I would like to not have that dot there, i.e. I want the output to be only

**Theorem 10** *Text of the theorem*.

I have about 200 appearances of this macro in the manuscript that consists of about 30 files and naturally want a not-too-painful way to achieve this. I tried redefining `\proclaim` into `\myproclaim`, but it does not seem to like # (nesting). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

such a weird choice of format but:

[image]

```
\input amstex
\documentstyle{amsppt}

\catcode`\@=11
\let\proclaim\relax
\outer\def\proclaim{%
  \let\savedef@\proclaim \let\proclaim\relax
  \add@missing\endroster \add@missing\enddefinition
  \add@missing\endproclaim \envir@stack\endproclaim
  \def\proclaim##1{\restoredef@\proclaim
    \penaltyandskip@{-100}\preproclaimskip
    {\def\usualspace{\/{\proclaimheadfont@\enspace}}%
     \varindent@\proclaimheadfont@\ignorespaces##1\unskip
     \frills@{%
%.
\enspace}}%
    \proclaimfont\ignorespaces}%
  \nofrillscheck\proclaim}
\catcode`\@=13

\proclaim{Theorem 10} 
Text of the theorem
\endproclaim

\bye
```

Comment: thank you. I was ready to rejoice, until I put it into my file(s). But then, for some strange reason it messes up my commutative diagrams, whether they are inside or outside the redefined proclaim environment. For instance, the following commutative diagram that comes out nicely before the (re)defining of proclaim  $$
\CD
 F @<{\al}<< X \\
@V{\pi_i}VV              @VV\al_j V \\
F(i) @>> {F(f)} > F(j)
\endCD
$$     comes out without arrows, to be more precise, they are shown verbatim as @ < <<  etc (the symbols like $\pi_i$ inside CD's do come out fine. It is the h or v arrows that do not work

Comment: Some time ago, I suggested to AMSTeX support person (who said that AMSTeX is no longer supported) that one should go to amsppt.sty file and remove the dot and I see that you seem to have done that, with appropriate changes, but why on earth are the arrows affected in commutative diagrams?

Comment: @Rado I edited the answer to  fix the com diag thing, catcode should be 13 not 12 in amstex (no one has used amstex since last millenium so it is easy to forget these things)

Comment: Thanks greatly! I will try it again and will let you know. Re the old AMSTeX, you are showing that you know the essence of things. There are too many people who know  say program version v.1, but cannot handle version v, because their knowledge is superficial, not essential. Surely TeX is TeX, the versions are just build up When that ceases, it should not be TeX any longer, but something else.

Comment: YEI!!!!! David, it works like a charm now. You are the master! Unless somebody comes up with a one liner answer, I think your solution should be characterized as definitive.

Comment: tex is tex, but tex is a language for defining document markup and typesetting languages. amstex was such a language but it is unused and unsupported, languages that no one uses do not really function as a language any more, so it is honestly just a bad choice for a document being written now.

Comment: Actually my manuscript was (mostly) written in the last millennium -- more than 300 pages of it. The problem with what is used or not is that one can keep chasing what is in vogue for the sake of vogue and one would never be on target. Of course, if one's primary goal is just typesetting it may even be fun. If, on the other hand it is just a means of neatly writing up the work one does, then a desire for a stable (let's talk 50 years) means for writing things up is preferable.

Comment: @Rado sure for an old book yes keep with the sources, I assumed from the questions it was a new work, but amsmath (the latex version of the amstex math layout)  was produced sometime around 1994 and amstex hasn't been supported since. You can't rely on egreg and me to live forever to answer amstex questions, so in case others are just passing by and see the answers I think it is important to flag in any such answer **do not do this** that does not mean that you should not ask, nor that we won't answer:-)

Comment: Wait, you and  egreg should be immortal!!! Do I understand you well: I should **not**  flag these answers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34261/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-rado).